# Portable Prism Windows Phone 8 Example?

Tags: windows-phone-8, prism

Is there somewhere an example for a simple Prism 4.1 based Windows Phone 8 project?

Trying to port over my Windows Store App to Phone 8.

I like to use the portable Prism project from https://github.com/xperiandri/PortablePrism / nuget PortablePrism.WP8 -Pre

Comment: Based on my understanding, the nuget you mentioned would not be related to Microsoft releases of **Prism**. In addition, **Prism for Windows Phone** library is targeted for **WP7**, providing support up to **Windows Phone 7.5**. Therefore, it might be hard to find a published sample, anyway it would not be an official **Prism** sample. You can find more related information in the following **CodePlex** [thread](https://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/461230).

Comment: I do not really care if the nuget package comes from MSFT. It seems that the Prism team there is fokusing more on the Windows Runtime version - maybe this will end up to be compatible with WP8 someday - the rumors of comverging APIs making sense...
Using the WP7 lib without Navigation support makes no real sense to me. The Windows Runtime version is supporting that.
So it might be better to stick with the MVVMLight library for now?